# Rewrite url with parameters in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i need rewrite this url in nginx, from:

> http://domain.com/index.php?src=pictures/2014/11/23/1ZWi3tmM.jpg&w=330&h=186&a=c

to something like this

> http://domain.com/thumb/300x186/ac/pictures/2014/11/23/1ZWi3tmM.jpg

i tried with this rule

> rewrite /thumb/([0-9.]+)x([0-9.]+)/ac/([A-Za-z0-9.]+) index?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3&a=c;

but no luck. Any suggestion?
I've no experience with nginx, sad but true. Thank you

Comment: Which of this url come from browser?

Comment: Any browser, on desktop or mobile.

Comment: **Which** of the urls above comes from browser?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean ?